# Using jQuery hide show mutiple times

Tags: jquery, click, hide, show

I'm using the code below to replace a minimize icon to an expand icon when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#expand").click(function(){
    $(".expandicon").hide();
    $(".shrinkicon").show();
  });
  $("#shrink").click(function(){
    $(".expandicon").show();
    $(".shrinkicon").hide();
  });
});
```

The only problem is I can only use it once (first instance then the second icon doesn't change and so on). All in all, I would have to use it 5 times as I have 5 tables in a single page. Any idea how to do it? I'm fairly new with web development, not to mention jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[EDIT] Here is my HTML code:

```
<span class="expandicon" style="display:none;">
  <a class="flip">
    <img id="expand" src="img/expand1.png" />
  </a>
</span>
<span class="shrinkicon">
  <a class="flip">
    <img id="shrink" src="img/shrink1.png" />
  </a>
</span>
```

*** will replace id's with classes instead. my bad on that one.

Comment: Show the relevant HTML structure (the tree around #expand/#shrink/icons). That's necessary to answer this question.

Comment: Protip: ID's have to be unique, it looks to me like you're using ID expand and shrink five times. Change that to a class or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
$(".expandicon").hide();
```

you hide all elements in the page with class='expandicon'

and with

```
$(".shrinkicon").show();
```

all elements with class='shrinkicon' are shown.

Have a look in [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

For your case, try this:

HTML:

```
<span class="expandicon" style="display:none;"> expand 1 </span>
<span class="shrinkicon"> shrink 1 </span>
<br/>
<span class="expandicon" style="display:none;"> expand 2 </span>
<span class="shrinkicon"> shrink 2</span>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('span.expandicon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggle().next('span.shrinkicon').toggle();    
    });
    $('span.shrinkicon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggle().prev('span.expandicon').toggle();        
    });
});
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sikrip/LtDQg/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! 'preciate it.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you much without HTML code but here are a few tips:

- you can use the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to hide / show dynamically an element depending on its previous state
- if you need to apply the same event to several elements, you'd better use **classes** instead of **ids** (remember that ids are **unique**)

[EDIT] Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/SShK6/

[EDIT 2] Here is an example with your HTML like: http://jsfiddle.net/ux8Nw/

Comment: Here's the HTML:

<span class="expandicon" style="display:none;"><a class="flip"><img id="expand" src="img/expand1.png" /></a></span><span class="shrinkicon"><a class="flip"><img id="shrink" src="img/shrink1.png" /></a></span>

Having the same problem with:
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

I can only use it once. If I use it on the next table, it hides both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to set the image as background. Than create a class shrink and expand and use `toggleClass()` ( http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ ) to switch between them on click.